# Doubt in triaxial stress state in a notched specimen

Tags: materials, metallurgy, material-science

In the book titled "Mechanical Metallurgy" written by G.E.Dieter I am having problems to understand why a notch in a material would mean a triaxial state of stress.I do well understand that notch would create stress concentrations in the material but why a triaxial state of stress is still beyond my understanding.
Somebody told me this,"Triaxial state means "the deformation tensor especially at the tip of notch can't be described by a simple uniaxial compression or tension type of deformations but also involves large shear deformations. Actually for the sharp tip associated stress tensor involves not only diagonal terms but also the off-diagonal terms, which means shear components. "However I do not understand even a part of it.A detailed answer to this is most welcome with the mathematical equations.

Comment: When you say "I don't understand even part of it," it's hard to know where to start answering the question. Do you even know what terms like "uniaxial and triaxial stress fields" and "deformation tensor" mean, for example? Equations won't help if you don't know what any of the symbols in them mean!

Comment: @alephzero I know only uniaxial stress field that you list the eigen values in a diagonal sense as the principal stresses.Nothing more than that.

Comment: @alephzero It would be very kind of you if you would reply to this.